# ¿Cómo puedo incluir el primer registro con un between sql? error en fetch

Tags: php, sql, fetch

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
$sql  = "SELECT correo FROM correo_usuarios WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100";
```

El problema es que no me incluye el primer registro

asi hago la impresion

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['correo'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Excluía el primer registro por esta linea.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Removida y problema solucionado